# Run python script in Django and produce live output buffer on the web

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am a beginner to Django web framework. I have a bunch of python scripts which runs and produce output on cli at present but I want the same scripts to run from django web and display live buffer output

Can anyone shed some light on how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

"Live" output will not be possible without using a more advanced technique or some JS. To get you started, execute the Python code in the view and then pass the results to a template to render them for the user (or as plain HttpResponse).

Have a look at the official docs to get you started if you are a total beginner: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something

Comment: Live output would be totally doable with a StreamingHTTPResponse, but the result wouldn't be very pretty.